# Exact same code (copy/paste) jQuery working in html file but not in CMS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, content-management-system

I have two pages - a simple HTML "code example" page from a jQuery code.  ( .html file  uploaded to server without any modifications)

The other page is the exact HTML copied from that .html code - but outputed by a CMS (Vbulletin Webtemplates CMS)

Working (.html file uploaded to server): [ Link removed - problem solved below ]

NOT working (copy of html file outputed by CMS):  [link removed]

Exact same code (copy/paste) - only difference if you view the page source is jqt.htm has google analytics code automatically thrown in there (I've tried taking out the analytics code so they're exactly the same, still doesn't work).

Anyone know what might be causing this?

I figure it's got something to do with HEADERS that I can't see - I've viewed the headers and can't figure out what would stop jQuery codes from working ...

Comment: Although links elsewhere can be a useful *adjunct* to a question, always put the relevant markup **in the question itself**. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: T.J. Crowder - I don't think posting the code would be useful - as the problem is that the code works in one situation - and not another.

Comment: `@user`: You copy what's working in one place, and what isn't working elsewhere. This question is useless if the code goes away. Read the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broken page is escaping the `$`:

`&#036;.noConflict();`

I'd guess that your CMS is probably escaping the character for some reason.

You should use Firebug to troubleshoot your JS problems, it's extremely easy to use and showed the error right when I loaded the page:

[image]